# Add running number and subtotal for each section in an excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have several worksheets that need to be combined into a worksheet with the additional running number and CountA on top for each separate section, and before the start of each new section I want to input the title.

I have recorded the modules for combining the worksheet as shown below.

```
Sub DUTY_FREE()

 Macro3 Macro

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
    Dim Lrow As Long
    
    'Lrow = Sheets("DUTY FREE").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count (range)
    Lrow = Sheets("DUTY FREE").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
  
    Sheets("DUTY FREE").Range("A1:AU" & Lrow).Copy
    
    Sheets("Combine").Select
    Sheets("Combine").Range("A1").Select
    
    Sheets("Combine").Paste
    
    
    Dim LrowTLS As Long
    
    Sheets("Combine").Select
    
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim LastRow2 As Long
    Dim rngTLS As Range
     
     lastrow = Sheets("Combine").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      LastRow2 = Sheets("Combine").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

Set rngTLS = Cells((LastRow2 + 2), 1)

   LrowTLS = Sheets("TLS").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Sheets("TLS").Range("A1:AU" & LrowTLS).Copy

    
    rngTLS.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
 End Sub

Sub Anntana()
    
    Dim LrowAnntana As Long
    
    Sheets("Combine").Select
    
    
    Dim LastRowAnntana1 As Long
    Dim LastRowAnntana2 As Long
    Dim rngAnntana As Range
     
    LastRowAnntana1 = Sheets("Combine").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowAnntana2 = Sheets("Combine").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

Set rngAnntana = Cells((LastRowAnntana2 + 2), 1)

   LrowAnntana = Sheets("Anntana").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Sheets("Anntana").Range("A1:AU" & LrowAnntana + 1).Copy

    
    rngAnntana.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

---

This is what I get from the code, I can do a combination of multiple criteria as expect, however I still cannot figure it out how to add some formula on top of each section.

[image]

Here is What I expect to get additional updated,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add running number for each section by finding data from column "B"
if there is no data the formula will return empty and start counting from 1 for the next part.

Sub addnumber ()

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim rngnumber As Range
Dim ws as worksheet
 
 lastrow = Sheets("Combine").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row.Offset(1).Row
```

Set rngnumber = Cells((LastRow + 2), 1)

```
Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[1]="""","""",IF(AND(ISFORMULA(R[-1]C[1]),R[-1]C=""""),1," & Chr(10) & "IF(AND(R[-1]C[1]<>"""",RC[1]=""""),""""")""

Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
Columns("A:A").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

End sub

For the count number on top of each part, I suggest adding more columns after you complete adding the running number but instead of finding text, you can look for number 1 which is the start number for each section, and you can find the right position of each title by offset function.

Comment: It seems to be working, but it starts running numbers from the title. without title it worked as I expected

Comment: do you need to add new data to each section?

Comment: No additional data need to be added,